# How to create a class which is sub class of two classes

Tags: ios

I have class called ViewController. How to make this class is a sub-class of "metaiosdkViewController" and "JWslideViewController". Help me with syntax.
i have written like this

```
@interface ViewController : MetaioSDKViewController,JWslideViewController
```

but this giving me error

Comment: It's supposed to error. No multiple inheritance in objective C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes objective-c doesnt support multiple inheritance but you can give one parent so

```
@interface ViewController : MetaioSDKViewController
```

and

```
 @interface MetaioSDKViewController : JWslideViewController
```

this is just an idea I know you can implement well as per your need

Answer (score 4):

objective-c doesn't support multiple inheritance,but if you want to add some extra behaviour you can achieve it through delegates..

Comment: They're not called "delegates" but "protocols".

Answer (score 1):

What is it that you want to achieve with multiple inheritance?
Do you want to override methods from each of these super classes?
Note that objective c provides 2 mechanisms for extensibility:

**1) Implementing a Protocol and make your object the delegate:**

```
@interface ViewController : <MetaioSDKViewController,JWslideViewController>
```

This enforces `ViewController` to implement certain methods as defined in contract by 2 delegates, and at some point in processing, they get called. If you don't implement them, they may simply not be called but you may not get desired functionality.

Example: `UITableViewDataSource` protocol that defines many methods that `UITableViewController` subclass implements. [cellForRowAtindexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW6) is very famous example of a delegate method that your own table view subclass must implement to draw your own custom cells.

Note that this is not the type of extensibility that subclasses provide in general sense. Your class does not extend any functionality here. Rather it becomes what it says - a delegate - someone who is assigned to do some task. Like you do:

```
yourTableView.delegate = self; //tell self to be the delegate of yourTableview
```

Library code does it's stuff and in some point in processing it calls `[delegate someMethod]`. If your own class implements it, it calls it, otherwise `delegate` will be nil, and it may just be NO-OP and you don't get desired functionality. Again, this is implementation-dependent. Maybe the protocol defines that the method is compulsory, in which case your class MUST implement this method in order to compile.

**2) Implement a category:**

This is sort of a shortcut way to extend library classes. They act like an extra stub which, when your code runs, attaches itself to the already existing memory layout of the library objects and provides extra functionality.

You can define a category on any of the in-built classes as well. In fact that is the primary objective it is used for. For example, [here](https://github.com/cyclestreets/ios/blob/master/lib/categories/NSString+HTML.m) is an NSString category which provides HTML conversion. There are hundreds of categories implemented as open source and they provide enormous benefits where library code falls short. Discussing their suitability in entirety is however out of scope for this discussion.

One thing to note however is: You do not override anything using a category. Rather you are supplying something in extra. For example if you want some custom drawing across all your app views, you can define a category on UIView in your project and then all your views could simply include the category header file. You don't even have to inherit from this category, you simply inherit from the base type.

e.g. in the NSString category example above, you do not have to define your NSString to be of type NSString+HTML. Instead you just include the responsible `NSString+HTML.h` file wherever you want those extra methods like `stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText` and so on. The changes remain limited to your project - to the files where you include this category.

Categories do not provide for extra data members - and that is something that only inheritance can provide. Yet, multiple inheritance among viewcontrollers is something you should definitely reconsider hundred times - you will see that what you are looking for is not multiple inheritance.